# Calling correctly a method of another class?

Tags: c#, winforms

See fellows I have a problem and is that i think my code is in a loop

And before you answer "RePoST" I have visited all the other threads and i still did not hit with a solution

```
namespace Triangle_Proportions
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public class Data : Form1
        {
            public static class Variables
            {
                public static int A;
                public static int B;
                public static int C;

                public static int a;
                public static int b;
                public static int c;
            }

            public void Set_Variables()
            {
                Variables.A = label0A.Left;
                Variables.B = label0B.Left;
                Variables.C = label0C.Left;

                Variables.a = label_a.Left;
                Variables.b = label_b.Left;
                Variables.c = label_c.Left;
            }
        }

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Data etc = new Data();
            etc.Set_Variables();
        }
    }
}
```

This part of the code its only goal is to call `Set_Variables();` after `InitializeComponent();`

I know I can solve this simply by just "quicking out" `Variables` and `Set_Variables` from `Data` but i want both to remain inside `Data` because is easier to look it up when searching this.

It doesn't have any syntax errors but every time I decide to call `Set_Variables();` the program never opens

Comment: Why do you have so many nested classes? Is that necessary? Why not just have separate classes?

Comment: Why is `Data` inheriting from `Form1`? That seems unnecessary (and the cause of your issues)

Comment: Form1() called. Data() called. Form1() called. Data() called. Form1() called. Data() called. Form1() called. Data() called. Form1() called. Data() called. Form1() called. Data() called. Form1() called. Data() called. KABOOM! Don't have Data inherit Form1

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have a recursion problem.

In the constructor of `Form1` you instaniate a new class which is also inherited from `Form1` which is calling the constructor again. See the problem?

Create a non static version:

```
public class Variables
{
    public int A;
    public int B;
}
```

And your Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Variables _variables;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _variables = new Variables
        {
            A = label0A.Left,
            B = label0B.Left
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Great you are a lifesaver that's what did it for me.


Note aside: i had to erase that semicolon after the bracket and stablish the variables like
_variables = new Variables();
            _variables.A = label0A.Left;
            _variables.B = label0B.Left;
            ...

Comment: @DanteSparda About the semicolon, not sure, I have no IDE here right now. But the other thing is called object initializer. It Should work like I have shown: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/object-and-collection-initializers (Maybe it only works with Properties, I never use public fields)